# CSS: select specific child

Tags: html, css

[image: I want to add border in the select element below using css, please help.]

I want to add border in the select element below using css, im new to web development it would be a great help if you can show me how, thankyou.

Comment: Please add the actual markup to the question and not a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a 1 pixel solid black border to just the element shown in your screenshot, the following CSS should do the trick:

```css
#menu-item-83 > .submenu {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The `#` prefix references an element by id. The `>` specifies that the following element should be a direct child of the preceding matched element. And the `.` prefix references an element by class name.

Comment: thankyou for answering but the code you give doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps there are more elements to the right in your screenshot that I can't see which make `.submenu` not a direct child of `#menu-item-83`. Try without the `>`. Does that work?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/599kzwpm9k119rx/htmlcode.txt -> here is the whole markup., yup kinda tried tweaking it like that.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
#menu-primary #menu-item-83 > ul.sub-menu {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ccd7tLxm/